# How to bold label on click?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So the labels are populated from the database. Once the label is clicked, the label need to turn red and bold. when clicked on another label, the first label need to come back to original state and the new label should be activated and it needs to be bold and red. for some reason, the changeActiveStates() only works for the first 2 labels, i.e., when first label is clicked it turns red and when the second label is clicked the first label is turned black and the second label is turned red. when the third label is clicked, the second label remains red and the third one turns red. How do i fix this??

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<span>
<input type="hidden" name="LiabFilter" id= "idLib<%=liabkey %>" value="<%=liabkey %>" />
<div>
<label for="idLib<%=liabkey%>" id="liablabel" style="cursor: hand; padding-left: 25px; font-weight: normal" 
                                    onClick ="clearLiabFilter();  
                                    document.getElementById('idLib<%=liabkey%>').checked = true; 
                                    changeActiveStates(this);">
<%=liab.getName() %> 
</br>
</label>
</div>
</span>
<style type="text/css">
               .activate { font-weight: bold; color:#e40000;}
               .visited{ font-weight: normal; color: #000000;}


                </style>
<script>
function byId(id) { 
    return document.getElementById ? document.getElementById(id) : document.all[id];
} 

var prevLink = ""; 

function changeActiveStates(ele) { 
    if (prevLink) byId(prevLink).className = '';
    ele.className = 'activate'; 
    prevLink = ele.id; 
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you averse to JQuery?

If not, this should work.

```
$('label').click(function() {
    $('label').removeClass('activate'); /* Remove 'activate' class from all labels */
    $(this).addClass('activate'); /* Add 'activate' class to clicked label
});
```

EDIT: [Example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ru3fb/)

EDIT: A little more detail as the questioner hasn't used JQuery before.

[JQuery is a javscript library](http://jquery.com/) and so must be loaded by the browser before you can do all the nifty stuff.

Add the following between the `<head></head>` tags on your page:

```
<script src="http//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

([Why let google host JQuery for you?](http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/))

Then add the following, also between the  tags but after the script tag given above:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('label').click(function() {
        $('label').removeClass('activate'); /* Remove 'activate' class from all labels */
        $(this).addClass('activate'); /* Add 'activate' class to clicked label
    });
});
```

([What does $(document).ready() do?](http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/09/introducing-document-ready))

Comment: Yup, my point exactly.  Looks like you beat me by a fraction of a second! :)

Comment: so, do i just add the jquery in the script tag with the other functions or should i create a new .js file. Sorry i have never worked with jQuery before.

Comment: Added some more to the answer. I hope it helps. JQuery is really useful and makes things like this incredibly easy. You should definitely check it out

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the best of solutions, but have you considered using jQuery? It's generally not too much of a dependency , and will solve these sort of issues quite elegantly and easily for you.  Plus. Cross-browser compatibility.